# Como pasar un script a Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, macos

Necesito convertir el documento de un script a un documento rmarkdown, cuando lo guardo en html , lo abro y no se ve como debería , ademas tampoco se como añadir un marco de valores para que me lo lea mardown.
gracias

Comment: Bienvenida a Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Hola Clara, recuerda que esto no es un foro, esperamos que las preguntas sean concretas y con toda la información necesaria para poder brindarte una respuesta.  Comentas que tienes un código en r-markdown que no estaría generando la salida que esperas, ese es un buen punto para empezar, agrega el código en cuestión, agrega una muestra de la salida que obtienes y explica en detalle que es lo que esperas y no logras. Sino, lamentablemente una pregunta como esta terminará cerrada. Suerte.